# Creando una tabla en Access con una consulta de unión

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Estoy haciendo una aplicación donde registro muchos datos desde diferentes tablas donde en todas ellas el campo común es la fecha. Realizo una consulta para ver todos los datos ingresados desde diferentes tablas por fecha, tal que así:

```
SELECT fecha, peso
FROM peso

UNION

SELECT fecha, cantidad
FROM banco

UNION 

select fecha, cantidad
from hucha

UNION 

select fecha, km_coche
from km

UNION select fecha, km_moto
from km
ORDER BY fecha;
```

Y me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: Captura de la consulta realizada]

La devolución de datos está bien, pero me gustaría realizar dos cosas:

- que me devuelva solo el día que realizo la consulta. Lo he intentado con =date() pero me devuelve todas las fechas
- intento que me aparezca el campo desde donde sale el dato (por ejemplo el último dato, 86,5, es el peso) en otra columna como detalle del dato.

Las tablas son:

```
PESO
id_peso
fecha
peso

BANCO
id_banco
fecha
cantidad

HUCHA
id_hucha
fecha
cantidad

KM
id_km
fecha
km_coche
km_moto
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que salga la procedencia del dato debes añadir un literal. Respecto del día, si te refieres al día de la fecha que muestras, tienes la función `day` para ello. Añado un `WHERE` para que solo aparezcan los registros de hoy. Si quieres que aparezcan los de ayer deberías hacer `WHERE Date() - 1 = fecha`

```
SELECT fecha, day(fecha) as dia, peso, 'Peso' as Dato
FROM peso
WHERE Date() = DatePart(fecha)
UNION
SELECT fecha, day(fecha) as dia, cantidad, 'Banco' as Dato
FROM banco
WHERE Date() = DatePart(fecha)
UNION 
select fecha, day(fecha) as dia, cantidad, 'Hucha' as Dato
from hucha
WHERE Date() = DatePart(fecha)
UNION 
select fecha, day(fecha) as dia, km_coche, 'Km coche' as Dato
from km
WHERE Date() = DatePart(fecha)
UNION 
select fecha, day(fecha) as dia, km_moto, 'Km moto' as Dato
from km
WHERE Date() = DatePart(fecha)
ORDER BY fecha;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, respecto al dato esto es lo que buscaba. Respecto a la fecha, lo que quiero es que salga SOLO el día que realizo la consulta. Es decir, por las noches quiero consultar todos los movimientos registrados durante ese mismo día. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: He añadido a la respuesta un `WHERE` para que filtre por los datos de hoy.

Comment: Gracias, acabo de verlo. Pero salen los datos del día 20 de cualquier mes. El formato que tengo de fecha es 'dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss', puesto que lo siguiente es hacer filtro por semanas, meses, trimestres y años. La hora no la necesito, pero ahí está.

Comment: He cambiado el `day()` por el `Date()`, creo que con eso lo tendrás.

Comment: Acabo de probarlo añadiendo unos datos hoy en un par de tablas pero no me devuelve nada. Entiendo que si no incluyo datos no tiene que aplicarse el filtro,  pero los datos están bien guardados en la tabla.

Comment: Además, me ha generado una columna llamada 'peso' donde aparece la cantidad de todos los campos, ya sea peso, cantidad de hucha o banco, km_moto y km_coche.

Comment: El problema es que la fecha almacenada contiene también la hora, Puedes probar con `DatePart(fecha)`, a ver si funciona. De otra forma deberíamos poner en el `Where day(Date()) = day(fecha) and month(Date()) = month(Fecha) and year(Date()) = year(Fecha)`

Comment: Creo que con esto está resuelto. Me aparece sólo el día de hoy en la consulta y aunque me aparece un campo "día" con el número 20 repetido en todos los campos, en el formulario donde meteré la consulta puedo no mostrarlo. Muchísimas gracias Roger.

Comment: Elimina ", day(fecha) as dia" de la consulta y lo tienes resuelto

Comment: Hecho y funcionando, muchísimas gracias de nuevo Roger